# Moment js format date with timezone

Tags: javascript, date, ember.js, momentjs

Hi I am using Ember+moment.js to format date in my ember helpers.

I am getting the following date from the service

**Tue Aug 23 2016 09:43:53 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)**

In my ember helper class i am able to format date using following code :

```
var formattedDate = moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a');
```

I am getting the following output :

**23/08/2016 9:43 am**

Expected Output : **23/08/2016 9:43 am GMT**

How can i specify the timezone flag in the format function?

Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: @Laurianti we do not have any placeholder(Like TZ) in moment?Because in my value itself i have the timeZone.

Comment: Did you try adding the `z` to the format string?

Comment: @locks Yes added but no luck instead of EST i am getting the following output "23/08/2016 9:43 am +2:00"

Comment: Sounds like Moment Timezone doesn't come included in the package you're using then, and you'll have to import it. You could try [ember-cli-moment-shim](https://emberobserver.com/addons/ember-cli-moment-shim).

Comment: @locks Yes i didn't include moment-timezone.js. For formatting date do we need 2-Libraries(Moment & moment-Timezone)? Yes i didn't use ember-cli-moment-shim because the document is not clear like moment.js

Comment: It _is_ moment.js, just wrapped so you can use it more easily inside Ember CLI projects.

Comment: @locks but i don't find any good documentation about ember-cli-moment-shim.Also the link you shares doesn't have ample enough examples about   the helpers supported by ember-cli-moment-shim

Comment: It doesn't have any helpers, it's just a wrapper so you can do `import moment from 'moment';`, which should be enough given the code in your question.

Comment: Will that resolve timezone issue?It contains both moment & moment-timezone.js?

Comment: It [claims that it does](https://github.com/jasonmit/ember-cli-moment-shim/blob/7fb27bf721190bc4462c5a595264da115ebb1b7a/README.md#enabling-moment-timezone). I would file a bug if it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Install ember-moment - `ember install ember-moment`
Install ember-cli-moment-shim - `ember install ember-cli-moment-shim`
stop and start `ember server`

To enable moment timezone, need to include `moment:{ includeTimezone: 'all' }` in config\environment.js

```
/* jshint node: true */

module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'App-Name',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',
    locationType: 'auto',
    moment: {
      // Options:
      // 'all' - all years, all timezones
      // '2010-2020' - 2010-2020, all timezones
      // 'none' - no data, just timezone API
      includeTimezone: 'all'
    },
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      }
    },

    APP: {
      // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
      // when it is created
    }
  };
  return ENV;
};
```

and then you can start use tz function and to get abbreviated time zone name you can include `z` flag in the format.

moment().tz('Asia/Calcutta').format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm a z')