# To display data from mock server into chartjs using ember

Tags: ember.js, chart.js, mockserver

I have data coming from mock-server, which I can view using ember inspector. I need to display these data in bar chart using chartjs.

This is my code from component - chart.js

import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
   updateGraph: function(){
    var barcontent = this.get('timeSeriesBarContent');
    console.log('updateGraph called');
    eventdata.forEach(function(item,index){
     timeSeriesBarContent.append({time: item.timeStamp, label: item.eventType, value: (item.event +" : "+ item.device) })
    });
  }.observes('eventdata'),
  timeSeriesBarContent: [{}];
```

And this is my code from template - chart.hbs

```
{{time-series-chart  barData=timeSeriesBarContent }}
```

The bar chart gets displayed if I use static data inside

```
timeSeriesBarContent: [{
time: d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d').parse("2013-05-15"),
       label: "test data",
       value: 49668,
       type: "money"
}];
```

But I am not being able to load the data coming from mock-server.
Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your component with some data and data comes from the `Route`...  In your `Route`'s `model` hook, you should return the records you have retrieved from the server.  In your template, use something like `{{time-series-chart barData=model}}` or some sub-object of your model.

Remember the `Route` is responsible for hooking up the data to your component in the route's template.  So:

1. Route's `model` hook returns records from the store
2. Route's template contains the component tag, connecting the component to the data.

Comment: Thank you for your response :) Can you tell me how I can update date format for the data coming from model? Should I built my own custom transforms and then use them ?

Answer (score 0):

- where is `eventdata` is defined , you need to use get function to access properties`this.get('eventdata')`
- it looks `eventdata` is an array so your observer should be `observes('eventdata.[]'),` only then this will be triggered for every time new item is added/removed.
- You can define `timeSeriesBarContent:[]` inside init() by overriding and in `updateGraph` method instead of `append` try to use `pushObject` method only then this will update bounding template.

  ```
  export default Ember.Component.extend({
  timeSeriesBarContent: [],
  eventData: [],
  init() {
      this._super(...arguments);
      this.set('timeSeriesBarContent', []);
      this.set('eventData', []);
  },
  updateGraph: Ember.on('init', Ember.observer('eventdata.[]', function() {
      var barcontent = this.get('timeSeriesBarContent');
      console.log('updateGraph called');
      this.get('eventdata').forEach(function(item, index) {
          barcontent.pushObject({ 'time': item.timeStamp, 'label': item.eventType, 'value': item.event + " : " + item.device })
      });
  })),
  ```

  });

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried the concept but yet the issue is not solved. I am using ember v2.8.0 and have data from mock server coming when I monitor using ember inspector but I am not being able to display it in charts. Please let me know if I need to provide further details to get this issue resolved.

Comment: @IsaacShrestha How are you including `component - chart.hbs` are you sending `eventdata` like this `{{component-chart eventData=eventData }}` ..if that's so then you can try running your `updateGraph` observer function after init or didInsertElement. like this ..`updateGraph: Ember.observer('eventdata.[]', function() { ....your code }).on('init')`

Comment: export default Ember.Component.extend({
 timeSeriesBarContent: [],
 eventdata: null,

 updateGraph: Ember.on('init', Ember.observer('eventdata', function() {
  var barcontent = this.get('timeSeriesBarContent');
  console.log('updateGraph called');
  this.get('eventdata').forEach(function(item) {
   barcontent.pushObject({ 'time': item.timeStamp, 'label': item.eventType, 'value': item.event + " : " + item.device });
  });


 })),

});

Comment: Shit I am sorry for the mess, I accidentally pressed entered and it cannot be erased now. After making following changes to chart-demo.js file

Comment: I am sorry for the above 3 comments. I have almost resolved the issue but stuck in changing the date format now.  I need time of the pushed object in this format: d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d').parse("2013-01-14");    Where and how should I update this format ? If I will be able to get time in this format, my chart will work. Thank you :)

Comment: `moment(item.timeStamp).format('%Y-%m-%d')`  To Install ember-moment - `ember install ember-moment`
Install ember-cli-moment-shim - `ember install ember-cli-moment-shim`
stop and start ember server. [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39111414/5771666)

Comment: This problem is resolved. Thank you. I am using d3 charts(bargraph) to display these data, I want to remove the labels displayed below x-axis but I am not able to find out how to do so. Can you help me solve this issue please?

Comment: I am not familiar with D3 charts, may be you can ask this as separate question tagged d3.js